# Terminology: Almost stable states

Tags: terminology, notation, fixed-point-theorems, stability

I have a question about fixed points which are almost stable.

I have an increasing transition function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ where $f(0)>0$ and $f(1)<1$ but I don't necessarily have continuity.

I call any $x$ that satisfies $f(x)=x$ as a steady state.

Part 1)
I can show that there exists a steady state $x$ with the property that

$\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta$ such that

If $y \in [x,x+\delta]$, then $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \overbrace{f\circ \ldots \circ f}^{n\text{ times}} (x) \in [x,x+\epsilon]$

This steady state is "almost" right absorbing because for sufficiently small right deviations, you will not necessarily end up at the steady state, but you cannot end up too far from it. However, I do not know if there is a more precise term for such a steady state.

Part 2)
I know that there is an $x$ which satisfies the following properties:

$\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $\forall y \in (x,x+\epsilon)$ it is the case that $f(y)<y$. (This is an absorbing state)

or
$\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists y \in (x,x+\epsilon)$ such that $f(y)=y$ or (This means that x is the limit of steady states from the right)

I've gone over many phrases for which to call such a steady state (right contained, right non-repelling), but I am not sure if there is some standard terminology for this kind of steady state. Notice that it is also equivalent to the condition that

$\forall \epsilon>0$

$\exists y \in (x,x+\epsilon)$ such that $f(y)\leq y$.

Comment: Perhaps the first one is referred to as Lyapunov stability?

Comment: Equicontinuity?

Comment: Hi Ville, thanks. I think that you mean uniform continuity and it's a nice idea, but not quite enough. I venture that you were going to suggest that with uniform continuity, y is close to f(y) and f(y) is close to f(f(y)), which is close to f(f(f(y))) and so on. But, unfortunately, even if it's true, the whole system may eventually drift very far from y. Also, I don't even have that f is continuous.

Comment: No I mean equicontinuity of $(f_n)_n$

Comment: $(f^n)_n$ I mean

Comment: I see. Based on your comment, it is now clear to me that for Part 1, it's necessary and sufficient for $F=\lim_n f^n$ to be continuous at a steady state.